# Выдает ошибку, типа кнопка должна иметь кортеж, а я не особо втыкаю. Мне в общем нужно сделать кнопку 0 шире, а как это сделать незнаю

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

***Ошибка:***

```py
Button.size_hint must be a list or a tuple
```

***Код:***

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import Config


Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 500)
Config.set('graphics', 'hight', 500)


class CalculatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.lbl = Label(text='', font_size=20, halign='right', valign='center', size_hint=(1, .4))
        self.btn_0 = Button(text ='0', size=(.2, 1), size_hint=None)

        boxlay = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        boxlay.add_widget(self.lbl)

        gridlay = GridLayout(cols=4, size_hint=(1, .6))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='7'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='8'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='9'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='x'))

        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='4'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='5'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='6'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='/'))

        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='1'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='2'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='3'))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='+'))

        gridlay.add_widget(self.btn_0)
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text=','))
        gridlay.add_widget(Button(text='='))

        boxlay.add_widget(gridlay)
        return boxlay


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

Comment: Мне просто нужно сделать, что бы кнопка 0 по шире была

Comment: `size_hint` должен быть кортежем, например: `size_hint=(None, None)`.

Comment: Ошибки нет, а вот с размером беда. Кнопки только уголок виден, а сама вниз влево ушла. Запустите, если можете.